# EasyMock TestCase Fails while checking Exception

Tags: java, easymock

I have written one test case for my code using EasyMock for checking BusinessServiceException.But the test case fails(not error).Can anyone tell me why it happens.That is why this testcase fails.

Java Code :

```
 public class ListHelper {
    @Resource(name = "shoppingListService")
    private ShoppingListService shoppingListService;
    public void setShoppingListService(ShoppingListService shoppingListService) {
            this.shoppingListService = shoppingListService;
        }


        Public Map<String, String> getShoppingListCount(String partnerId, String userId){
                // Shopping List Section
                Map<String, String> shoppingListDetails = null;
                try {
                    shoppingListDetails = shoppingListService.getShoppingListTotal(partnerId, userId);
                } catch (BusinessServiceException e) {
                }
                return shoppingListDetails;
            }
```

EasyMock Test:

```
@Test(expected= BusinessServiceException.class)
public void testGetShoppingListCountBusinessServiceException() throws BusinessServiceException{

    EasyMock.expect(shoppingListService.getShoppingListTotal("p120-90", "2012")).andThrow(new BusinessServiceException("Failure"));
    EasyMock.replay(shoppingListService);
    try{
    listHelper.getShoppingListCount("p120-90", "2012");
    }finally{
    EasyMock.verify(shoppingListService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `listHelper` and not `shoppingListService`? And how does your testcase fails? No Exception?

Comment: ShoppingListService is an interface.The method which I am testing is in ListHelper.In failure trace it shows "java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: com.coupons.nextgen.exception.BusinessServiceException"

Comment: Can you show us more code? I don't see where you pass the mock (shoppingListService) to the object under test (listHelper). I would suspect something like: `listHelper = new ListHelper(shoppingListService);`

Comment: Hi I have uploaded full code...please check that.

Answer (score 1):

- **Your method does not throw an exception, because you discard it in the empty catch block.**

You should change your method to something like this:

```
public Map<String, String> getShoppingListCount(String partnerId, String userId) throws BusinessServiceException {
    // Shopping List Section
    Map<String, String> shoppingListDetails = shoppingListService.getShoppingListTotal(partnerId, userId); // do not catch the possible exception

    return shoppingListDetails;
}
```

- **Your test code does not pass the mock to the class under test.**

The test could look something like this:

```
@Test(expected= BusinessServiceException.class)
public void testGetShoppingListCountBusinessServiceException() throws BusinessServiceException {

    EasyMock.expect(shoppingListService.getShoppingListTotal("p120-90", "2012")).andThrow(new BusinessServiceException("Failure"));
    EasyMock.replay(shoppingListService);

    // pass the mock!
    ListHelper listHelper = new ListHelper(shoppingListService);

    try{
        listHelper.getShoppingListCount("p120-90", "2012");
    }finally{
        EasyMock.verify(shoppingListService);
    }
}
```